# Highlight 2 sheets by unique ID - new row, deleted row, non matching cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops, compare

Hi I have two sheets in the same file - Sheet1 and Sheet2.  Column A combines two cells in the row to create a unique ID for each row.  I need to loop through each row on sheet 1 and highlight the following conditions:

1. Row on Sheet 1, NOT Sheet 2 - Highlight all non empty cells on Sheet 1 for this row green.
2. Row on Sheet 2, NOT Sheet 1 - Highlight all non empty cells on Sheet 2 for this row yellow.
3. If a match is found - regardless of row number - highlight ONLY cell columns in that row that do not match red.

I have code that is looping through each unique ID row on sheet 1, however, when the row doesn't match because a record doesn't exist on sheet 1, it erroneously highlights errors that are not errors.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()
Dim ds1 As Range, ds2 As Range, row As Range, col As Range, f As Range

Set ds1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<--| change "DataSet1" to your actual "Data Set 1" sheet name
Set ds2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<--| change "DataSet2" to your actual "Data Set 2" sheet name

For Each row In ds1.Columns(1).Cells '<--| loop through "Data Set 1" "UniqueID" values (in its column 1)
    Set f = ds2.Columns(1).Find(what:=row.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| look for current UniqueID in "Data Set 2" column 1
    If Not f Is Nothing Then '<-- if "Data Set 1" "UniqueID" found in "Data Set 2", then...
        For Each col In ds1.Rows(row.row).Cells '<--| ...loop through "Data Set 1" "UniqueID" row cells...
            If col.Value <> ds2(col.row, col.Column) Then '<--| ... if current cell value doesn't match corresponding "Data Set 2" one, then ...
                col.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) '<--| ...mark "Data Set 1" current cell...
                ds2(col.row, col.Column).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) '<--| ...mark corresponding "Data Set 2" one
            End If
        Next col
    End If
Next row
End Sub
```

Example Output:
[image: Example Output Image - green new row on sheet 1, yellow is row that was deleted in sheet 1 and red are rows found on both sheets based on UniqueID but with highlighted changes for cell variations.. in both cases the tables are mixed order]

Comment: Can you give a short data example that reflects the issue (see also [mcve])? Or a screenshot that show what you want and what you actually get?

Comment: Also note that if you just want to compare 2 sheets there is a built in tool in office for that called Spreadsheet Compare: See [Basic tasks in Spreadsheet Compare](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/basic-tasks-in-spreadsheet-compare-f2b20af8-a6d3-4780-8011-f15b3229f5d8). • Not a VBA soulution but eventually what you are looking for.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i've edited the posted and added a screenshot of potential output.  No I would not want a loop through empty cells based on column A.

Comment: @TimWilliams def missed that! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
If col.Value <> ds2(col.row, col.Column) Then
```

should be

```
If col.Value <> ds2(f.row, col.Column) Then
```

Similarly

```
ds2(f.row, col.Column).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Currently you're not using `f` anywhere...

Comment: `f` is the matching cell in ColA in the range `ds2`, so if you want to highlight cells in that row you need to use `f.Row`.   `col` is a range in `ds1` so you can't use its `Row` to locate cells in `ds2`

Comment: These updates solved issues in the code.  Thank you.  While it is written yet to flag new or deleted rows, this got me much closer to 95% of the changes I was concerned with.